# How to get guarded_name of route I get from getRoutes method on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to get guarded_name of route I get from getRoutes() method on Laravel.
I can get route name by getName() method. But how to get wether the route is guarded for web or api of that route name?

Comment: I don't know what this 'guarded_name' is supposed to be ... you want to know the middleware that is used for the route?

Comment: In spatie/permission guarded_name is first middleware that actually contain web or api.

Comment: are you talking about the 'web' or 'api' groups of middleware or some parameter you are passing to a middleware?

Comment: I don't know how to call it. I need to get route that come from web or api I have defined on web or api route file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer from group discussion.

```php
$route->getAction('middleware')
```

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the middleware applied on the route

```php
Route::current()->computedMiddleware;
```

Comment: I don't know why this method redirects page, not printed what I need.